# how to get html text in <strong> tag using python

Tags: python

I have tried multiple methods to no avail.

I have this simple html that I want to extract the number 373 and then do some division.

```html
<span id="ctl00_cph1_lblRecCount">Records Found: <strong> 373</strong></span>
```

I attempted to get the number with this python script below

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium import webdriver
import urllib3
import re




NSNpreviousAwardRef = "https://www.dibbs.bsm.dla.mil/Awards/AwdRecs.aspx?Category=nsn&TypeSrch=cq&Value="+NSN+"&Scope=all&Sort=nsn&EndDate=&StartDate=&lowCnt=&hiCnt="                   

                NSNdriver.get(NSNpreviousAwardRef)


                previousAwardSoup = BeautifulSoup(NSNdriver.page_source,"html5lib");

                            # parsing of table
                try:
                    totalPrevAward = previousAwardSoup.find("span", {"id": "ctl00_cph1_lblRecCount"}).strong.text
                    awardpagetotala = float(totalPrevAward) / (50)
                    awardpagetotal = math.ceil(awardpagetotala)+1
                    print(date)
                    print("total previous awards: "+ str(totalPrevAward))
                    print("page total : "+ str(awardpagetotal))
                except Exception as e:
                    print(e) 
                    continue
```

all I get is this error

> 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'strong'

I tried parse the html as lxml and still the same error. What am I doing wrongly and how can I fix it

Comment: Did you find the answer to your problem?

Answer (score 1):

The code to access the `strong` tag, `soup.find("span").strong`, is perfectly right.
You can explicitly try it by putting that html line in a variable, and creating your `BeautifulSoup` object from that variable.

Now, the error clearly tells you that the `span` tag you're looking for does not exist.
So here are some potential sources of the problem, off the top of my head:

- Are you sure of the html input you feed into `BeautifulSoup` to create `previousAwardSoup`?
- Are you sure that the `id` attribute is correct? More specifically, is it always the same and not randomized?

Answer (score 0):

Print your previousAwardSoup and check if it has the span tag that you're searching for.

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow! Since OP was kind enough to post what looks like a runnable example, it is often a "better" approach to run this and, in your answer, point out any errors you encounter and how to fix them!